# CSS Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for advice on creating a drop down menu using Unordered Lists. I  have managed to get a horizontal unordered list by using the following CSS and HTML. I'd like to make it so on some of the menus a drop down menu appears.

I've tried multiple different methods and haven't managed to get it right.

**CSS**

```
#nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;


}

#nav li a {
    color: #f9f7ee;
    background-image:url(images/bullet.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    background-image:url(images/bulletsolid.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left: 16px;
    color: #f9f7ee;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teaching</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Performing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Was the Pastebin really necessary for that much code?

Comment: Just googling "css dropdown menu" shows the following interesting results: [PureCSSMenu.com](http://purecssmenu.com/), [Creating a pure CSS dropdown menu](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/), [Son of Suckerfish Dropdowns](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/)...

Comment: Just use this online tool: http://purecssmenu.com/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too hard with css involving nesting your unordered lists and hiding the nested ones until the parent li is hovered.  Here's a quick example if you wanted drop down below About. your html for it would look like so.

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">drop down below about 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">drop down below about 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

#nav ul {
display: none;
}

#nav li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
```

This will hide the child ul until the parent ul's li is hovered basically.

Answer (score 0):

If your interested in building accesibile CSS check out a list apart
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/
There one of my favourites sites for good standards and proper CSS foundation